# Apple Keychain passwords do not sync between my Mac and iPhone?

Tags: iphone, mac, password, keychain

It's quite annoying that I register on a site using my phone but the login info does not sync to my Mac when trying to sign in there. Mac OSX and iOS 10.

Comment: Why would it? Are you using iCloud keychain? Are you storing the password for this site there?

Comment: Obviously i'd be using iCloud keychain why on earth would I ask this question otherwise?